# JSON, MVC2 Disordered data in even cell cointainers

Tags: json, list, asp.net-mvc-2, jqgrid

I got into troubles trying to feed the jqgrid with required information. I did everything as suppose to be done, but apparently there is an issue.
Every second cell is order differently, so first row is ok:
[{"id":"AA1","cell":["AA1","AD + DNS + WINS","dev"]},

but the next one is ordered like below:

{"id":"AA2","cell":["dev","AD + DNS + WINS","AA2"]}

when 3rd is ok, and 4th is disordered and so on.

Code which is responsible for this process is below:

```
 var jsonData = new
        {
            total = totalPages,
            page = page,
            records = totalRecords,
            rows = (
              from l in lst
              select new
              {
                  id = l.HostName,
                  cell = new List<string> {
      l.HostName, l.Description, l.Type
    }
              }).ToArray()
        };
        return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Why is like that? I was trying use instead of List the String[], but Linq doesn't like that and pop up error, which suggest List instead of string array.
Is there any way to sustain desired order?

Answer (score 0):

What was your code to use string[]? I got this working without any trouble:

```
var jsonData = new
{
    total = totalPages,
    page = page,
    records = totalRecords,
    rows = (from l in lst
        select new
        {
            id = l.HostName,
            cell = new string[] {
                l.HostName,
                l.Description,
                l.Type
            }
        }).ToArray()
};
```

You can find similar samples [here](http://tpeczek.blogspot.com/2009/10/jqgrid-and-aspnet-mvc-basics.html) (but remember that in general they are very old and I would suggest looking at more up to date ones [here](http://tpeczek.codeplex.com/releases/view/61796) or [here](http://tpeczek.codeplex.com/releases/view/62741)).